# Parse Custom Date and Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, sorting, date

I'm new to javascript/jQuery and am attempting something ambitious for my skill level. I found some snippets that have helped but am stuck.

I have a bunch of dates in the format like this: dd-month-yyyy (10-Oct-2013). As far as I understand this is somewhat of an unconventional format for a date. So what I'm trying to do is parse the date into a normal format, and then arrange the parent divs using the jQuery tinysort plugin (which I don't think I am using correctly).

I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8BYDZ/

Or here is my code:

```
<div id="date-sort">
  <div class="date-content"> 
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p class="date-sort">10-Oct-2013</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="date-content"> 
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p class="date-sort">12-Oct-2013</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="date-content"> 
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p class="date-sort">2-Sep-2013</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="date-content"> 
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p class="date-sort">22-Jun-2013</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="date-content"> 
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p class="date-sort">1-May-2013</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function customParse(str) {
      var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                    'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
          n = months.length, re = /(\d{2})-([a-z]{3})-(\d{4})/i, matches;

      while(n--) { months[months[n]]=n; } // map month names to their index :)

      matches = str.match(re); // extract date parts from string

      return new Date(matches[3], months[matches[2]], matches[1]);
    }

    var array = [];

    var elements = $('.date-sort');

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var current = elements[i];
        if(current.children.length === 0 && current.textContent.replace(/ |\n/g,'') !== '') {
           // Check the element has no children && that it is not empty
           customParse(current.textContent);
           array.push(current.textContent);
        }
    } 

    $('div#date-sort>.date-content>.date-sort').tsort();

});
```

Thanks for any help, insight, or input.

Comment: You need to revise your question to something more specific, instead of asking for insight, etc.

Comment: Besides the errors fixed you can find in Kavun's answer below, you will have issues with the textContent property: It is not supported in IE <9. It uses innerText instead. You use jQuery anyway so I would suggest to use the text() method of jQuery instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give tinysort a sortable date.

```
new Date(matches[3], months[matches[2]], matches[1]).toJSON();

// ...

current.setAttribute('data-date', customParse(current.textContent));

// ...

$('div#date-sort>.date-content').tsort('.date-sort', {attr: 'data-date' });
```

Your regular expression was too restrictive as days are not always two numbers.

```
re = /(\d{1,2})-([a-z]{3})-(\d{4})/i
```

[Here is a working jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BYDZ/3/)

Comment: Almost. Add a valueOf() call after the customParse. I did the same mistake in my first version ;)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to eliminate the `-` marks with `.replace()`, then by using `new Date().getTime()` you assign the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and your Dates to an Array that will `.sort()` just how you need it to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ds = $('.date-sort'), dt = [];
  ds.each(function(i){
    dt[i] = new Date($(this).html().replace(/-/g, ' ')).getTime();
  });
  dt.sort();
  ds.each(function(i){
    $(this).html(new Date(dt[i])/*add . whatever here*/);
  });    
});
```

I updated your **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BYDZ/8/)**.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects are generally considered the best way to create associative maps (as the commentors pointed out below, it's perfectly valid to set a property on an array).

I would use an object as your map between month names and numbers.  Also, I would use lowercase names, so I could pay the cost of lowercasing once, and use that value in my mapping.

So I would replace the definition of your `months` array with an object initializer:

```
var months = { 'jan': 1, 'feb': 2, 'mar': 3, /*...*/ };
```

In that way, you don't need the loop.

Now you just need to call `.toLowercase()` on your input, and the month names will map correctly.

Comment: He isn't setting a string index on an array. He's using bracket notation to access a named property on the array (which is just an object at the end of the day). `var arr = [1]; arr['test'] = 2; console.log(arr);` will output the array but also the added property `test`.

Comment: I have to disagree. That line, albeit maybe ugly, is completely valid and working. What it does is it sets the Jan, Feb... properties of the month array to their index. As in: months.Jan = 0, months.Feb = 1, ... the ['Jan'] notation is used to create those properties.

Comment: Yes, Kavun, you're right.  I'll update my answer accordingly.  I dislike using arrays in this manner, but you're correct in your assertion.

Comment: I stand corrected, gentlemen.  I ran the code and printed out the value of `months`, and briefly forgot about the true nature of arrays in JavaScript (they are objects with properties, but the properties are not enumerable, which is why they don't get printed out).